# Look up hostname from Maven

Tags: maven, properties, environment-variables, localhost, pom.xml

I'm looking for a way to look up hostname and set it as a property in Maven.

This does not work in all environments:

```
...
<properties>
   <hostname>${env.HOSTNAME}</hostname>
</properties>
...
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you need that in a real build or only inside a CI environment ?

Comment: I want to filter test-property files substituting ${hostname} with the hostname where it's run. This is useful for local builds and for CI environments. For "real" builds the hostname in the property file is hard coded. This is to make sure the property file is for the correct environment.

Comment: Why not creating artifacts for every environment you need instead of making a build environment depend ? What about this: http://blog.soebes.de/index.php?/archives/340-Maven-Configuration-For-Multipe-Environments.html

Comment: That would require every developer to have their own config and manually add their hostname. The resulting artifacts are not environment dependent. The same binary is deployed to any environment. In each environment I have a property file with "secret" passwords that should not be checked in to source control or exist in other environments. When developers are building locally for test purposes I would like the build to generate the appropriate property file for the local environment based on filtering of the property file replacing placeholders with properties in the pom.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use a groovy script to set the project property

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>execute</goal>
              </goals>
               <configuration>
                  <source>
                  project.properties["hostname"] = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()
                 </source>
             </configuration>
         </execution>
      </executions>
 </plugin>
```

Comment: Hard to believe Maven can't expose this info any other way.  Nice hack, though.  Do you know of other properties that are typically set in this fashion?

Comment: @cwash Hack? agreed. It's required for items of information not available to Maven as a system or environment property. See: http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-properties.html

Comment: Remember that a host may have different names / ip addresses / interfaces, so there is no unique property for the host's name available. I am not sure about what InetAdress.getLocalHost() will do in such a case. Granted, with development machines this won't be the case most of the times.

Comment: How exactly do you use this? I have that plugin in build > plugingManagement > plugins. Is that enough? Can I just use `${hostname}` in a property after that?

Comment: Yes, you can use ${hostname}

Answer (score 4):

${env.COMPUTERNAME} works for me..

Comment: Though I guess this is windows specific

Answer (score 3):

The Maven Build Helper plugin 3.1.0 was just released with goals for getting the hostname, ip address, port reserving etc (http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html).

Add this to build plugins:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>init-build-properties</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>hostname</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <hostnameProperty>my.hostname</hostnameProperty>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up with a simple solution to the cross-plattform problem:

```
<manifestEntries>  
    <Build-Host-Linux>${env.HOSTNAME}</Build-Host-Linux>
    <Build-Host-Windows>${env.COMPUTERNAME}</Build-Host-Windows>
</manifestEntries>
```

Comment: That's weird. RHEL6 is OK with this. Are you sure you had env.HOSTNAME and not just HOSTNAME?

Answer (score 1):

The comment posted by user1885834 was working best for me: Create profiles for Windows and Linux and use the respective environment variables to define a new property ${hostname}, to be used anywhere.

```
<profile>
   <id>unix</id>
   <activation>
      <os>
         <family>unix</family>
      </os>
   </activation>
   <properties>
      <hostname>${env.HOSTNAME}</hostname>
   </properties>
</profile>
<profile>
   <id>windows</id>
   <activation>
      <os>
         <family>Windows</family>
      </os>
   </activation>
   <properties>
      <hostname>${env.COMPUTERNAME}</hostname>
   </properties>
</profile>
```

Comment: only that HOSTNAME is not defined on RedHat :(