# Maven dump file on ftp server when deploying

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ftp, m2eclipse

My Maven builds a ready zipped package that just has to be uploaded to a ftp server.

Is there a plugin for this task? It should start when I choose the `deploy` goal.

I see some ftp support for the real way Maven deploys files, but nothing for a custom ftp upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by a "custom" upload?

The deploy plugin doco describes how to normally deploy a build artifact [using ftp](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploy-ftp.html).

Comment: It just some custom gernerated zip file, but not a fancy Maven artifact with a POM. Or is there a way to define some fileSet?

Comment: Sounds like you need to reach for the  Maven ANT plugin (to run the ftp task) http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/

Comment: If you do decide to use ANT, don't forget the FTP task has a dependency on commons-net. http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#commons-net

Comment: Thanks, I already though I might have to do that. My dreams of an ANT free build are diminishing :-(

Comment: Simpler than writing a Maven plugin :-) Another option is an embedded groovy script. For an example see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441265/look-up-hostname-from-maven/7450469#7450469