# Does Maven Have a mechanism to read the machine name

Tags: maven, maven-3

I'm writing a Maven project and I'd like to include a file in the generated WAR that will contain some build time information. Typically this will be things like

- The build time/date stamp
- The user name of the person who built the WAR
- The version of the app as specified in the POM

These are all fairly easy as there are maven properties which will give me the information I need.

I'd also like to include the machine name. I know Windows stores this information in an environment variable called "COMPUTERNAME", while *nix uses the `hostname` command.

Is there some platform independent way of grabbing this information so that I can write it into my text file?

Comment: This might work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7450469/966590

Comment: Perfect - thanks.
Q: How do I mark this as an answer so other people can follow it?

Comment: You can write an answer to your own question and mark it as accepted. If you want me to, I can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Andrew Logvinov says,

- [Look up hostname from Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441265/look-up-hostname-from-maven/7450469#7450469)

Thanks :-)

Comment: I'm going with this as a solution. It feels cleaner and doesn't require OS specific tools.

Answer (score 0):

I did this by invoking the Maven Ant task. Within that I used the following Ant tasks:

`<tstamp>` to generate a timestamp property
`<propertyfile>` to create a properties file containing properties like the above timestamp, the username etc.

You could use the Ant `<exec>` task to execute `hostname` and nominate an output property to write this value into.

This created a properties file in the `src/main/resources` dir that I then embedded in the .war file

Comment: Thanks, but I'm specifically interested in the machine name. Writing values into a prepared file is trivial (I've already got it working for username, time stamp etc)

Comment: See my comment re. hostname above

Comment: I see - I knew the command "hostname" worked on *nix, but didn't know it was available on Windows as well. Ta