# SpringBoot / RabbitMq integration tests not working anymore on different environment

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I have a test suite running fine on a Windows Jenkins slave and locally (on Windows), and we are now migrating our Jenkins slave on a Docker Linux image.

The build that was fine is not running properly on the new slave, where we see failures on integration tests, especially the ones that expect to receive some messages from RabbitMq. 
Java and Maven versions may be slightly different on the new Linux slave, but I don't understand why something that was running fine for months isn't anymore on that new environment.

I find it quite difficult to debug, and I'm not sure where to start since it's working on my machine..

Did anyone already face that kind of behavior and could suggest pointers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I solved the issue : I didn't want to add too many Thread.sleep() in my test to allow me to check in real time on RabbitMq UI if I could see the messages going through and being consumed... so I added more logs.

I quickly found that the message was consumed by a listener, even though my test was failing. My test tries to check that when there's a failure during processing, the message is sent to deadletter queue. So I have a listener on deadletter queue. Here's a quick summary of what I could see in the logs :

```
18:51:05 2017-06-16 18:51:04,907 [main] DEBUG KickOffEventListenerIT    - sent message !!
...
18:51:05 2017-06-16 18:51:04,970 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] INFO  DeadLetterQueueListener   - received a message on deadletter queue
```

but my test was failing :

```
    deadLetterQueueListener.getLatch().await(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    assertThat(deadLetterQueueListener.getReceivedMessages()).isNotEmpty();
```

was giving :

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Expecting actual not to be empty
```

I did 2 things :

1. **making sure queues/exchanges are unique during my build**

I had a doubt that I may have several consumers on the queue, due to some other jobs running in parallel and connecting on same exchanges / queues. So I wanted to make sure the names were unique for each run.

Following [Look up hostname from Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441265/look-up-hostname-from-maven), this is what I did :

- configure Maven build to get access to hostname and inject it later, through this Maven plugin config (below config should be wrapped in a *plugin* XML element, but for some reason, stackoverflow doesn't accept it):

  ```
  <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
  <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.5</version>
  <executions>
      <execution>
          <phase>generate-resources</phase>
          <goals>
              <goal>execute</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
              <providerSelection>2.0</providerSelection>
              <source>
                  project.properties["hostname"] = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()
              </source>
          </configuration>
      </execution>
  </executions>
  ```

and configured my application like this :

```
myApp.messaging:
            dead.letter:
                    exchange:
                        name: myApp.dead.letter.exchange-@hostname@
                    queue:
                        name: myApp.dead.letter.queue-@hostname@
```

This way, queues/exchanges get created like this :

```
DEBUG RabbitAdmin - declaring Exchange 'myApp.dead.letter.exchange-d11525d215a8'
DEBUG RabbitAdmin - declaring Queue 'myApp.dead.letter.queue-d11525d215a8'
```

Since for every job, Docker spins a new "machine", the hostname is different each time. But despite this, it was still not working. 
I added more logs in the tests and in the listener, because I had a doubt : the only reason that could explain the issue is that I'm not asserting against the listener that I should. I could see in the logs :

- in my test :

  ```
  DEBUG KickOffEventListenerIT    - sent message !!
  DEBUG KickOffEventListenerIT    - waiting infos from deadLetterQueueListener myApp.remote.service.mocks.DeadLetterQueueListener@37093884
  DEBUG KickOffEventListenerIT    - waiting infos from latch java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch@7e2e2d7d[Count = 1]
  ```
- In the listener :

  ```
  DEBUG DeadLetterQueueListener   - processing infos from deadLetterQueueListener myApp.remote.service.mocks.DeadLetterQueueListener@2142ab69
  DEBUG DeadLetterQueueListener   - processing infos from latchjava.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch@79f8793b[Count = 1]
  INFO  DeadLetterQueueListener   - deadletter queue received message size : 1
  ```

--> I could see very clearly that the reference of the listener I'm asserting from and the reference of the listener that was getting the message was different ! Clearly, that's why my test is failing.

--> somewhere in my test suite, another listener was still active and consuming the message.

2. **Identify clearly which consumer gets the message**

To do this, I logged clearly the ID of the listener at creation time :

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class DeadLetterQueueListener {

    @PostConstruct
    public void logReferenceId(){
        log.debug("just built deadLetterQueueListener : "+this);
    }

    ...
}
```

Then it became obvious by looking at the object references in the logs :

```
19:24:21 Running myApp.service.impl.RequestCodeGeneratorServiceImplIT
19:24:23 2017-06-16 19:24:22,907 [main] DEBUG DeadLetterQueueListener   - just built deadLetterQueueListener :  myApp.remote.service.mocks.DeadLetterQueueListener@58984698
19:24:28 Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 6.058 sec - in myApp.service.impl.RequestCodeGeneratorServiceImplIT


19:24:29 Running myApp.messaging.incoming.KickOffEventListenerIT
19:24:30 2017-06-16 19:24:29,913 [main] DEBUG DeadLetterQueueListener   - just built deadLetterQueueListener : myApp.remote.service.mocks.DeadLetterQueueListener@32096336
19:24:31 2017-06-16 19:24:31,187 [main] DEBUG KickOffEventListenerIT    - waiting infos from deadLetterQueueListener myApp.remote.service.mocks.DeadLetterQueueListener@32096336
19:24:31 2017-06-16 19:24:31,250 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG DeadLetterQueueListener   - processing infos from deadLetterQueueListener myApp.remote.service.mocks.DeadLetterQueueListener@58984698
```

I had the confirmation that a "zombie listener" from a previous test was still alive and consuming the message, instead of the listener I created in my test. I checked in that first test (RequestCodeGeneratorServiceImplIT), and noticed that **it did NOT have the @DirtiesContext annotation**. I added it to make sure everything was cleaned up, and now my test suite passes !

Even though I found the solution to my issue, a few things are still not clear to me :
- how a minor difference in java/maven version can have that kind of impact ?
- how come the listener from the previous test is still up and running, despte the test finishing correctly ? 
- do I really have to put @DirtiesContext on all my integration tests that load a Spring context ?

If anyone has some answers to this, I would be interested.

Comment: "do I really have to put @DirtiesContext on all my integration tests that load a Spring context ?" Did you ever find out? I think I am having the same problem. Even though tests are annotated with @DirtiesContext, some old instance(s) of `RabbitListeners` survive and then receive messages that re not meant for them in later tests.

Comment: no, I haven't really found out.. but in the meantime, the steps in the response should help you to identify in which test that zombie listener gets created - you may miss one DirtiesContext on that test !

Comment: Yes, that helped. In my case `DirtiesContext` doesn't seem to actually deregister the listener though. I am currently evaluating if its better to use a mocked Rabbit by default in IntegrationTests and only using the real one in IntegrationTests that require a real Rabbit. This can probably be decided with a spring profile. With this one could probably avoid having to add `DirtiesContext` to a bunch of tests that are not related.